# How does one set the mouse on a remote HPC?

Tags: tmux

I am running tmux on a remote HPC but the mouse scrolling for history does not work. I know it usually works if one does:

```
C-b :
```

to get into command mode. Then:

```
setw -g mouse on
```

to turn the mouse on. But when I do that it doesn't like it:

```
Ambiguous option: mouse
```

Is this not possibel? How do I do it?

related: https://superuser.com/questions/210125/scroll-shell-output-with-mouse-in-tmux

Answer (score 5):

For me, on tmux v1.8, the following command worked:
`set -g mode-mouse on`

Other mouse related excerpts from `man tmux` :

```
mouse-resize-pane [on | off]
             If on, tmux captures the mouse and allows panes to be resized by dragging on their
             borders.

mouse-select-pane [on | off]
             If on, tmux captures the mouse and when a window is split into multiple panes the
             mouse may be used to select the current pane.  The mouse click is also passed 
             through to the application as normal.

mouse-select-window [on | off]
             If on, clicking the mouse on a window name in the status line will select that win‐
             dow.

mouse-utf8 [on | off]
             If enabled, request mouse input as UTF-8 on UTF-8 terminals.
.
.
.
mode-mouse [on | off | copy-mode]
             Mouse state in modes.  If on, the mouse may be used to enter copy mode and copy a
             selection by dragging, to enter copy mode and scroll with the mouse wheel, or to
             select an option in choice mode.  If set to copy-mode, the mouse behaves as set to
             on, but cannot be used to enter copy mode.
```

Comment: `setw -g mouse on` worked for my tmux version 3.2a